# Ngrok unrecognized command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash, twilio, ngrok

I'm trying to integrate the twilio api to work with an app Im writting. I followed every step on the guide and I downloaded and put the binary inside my project folder.

I followed a tutorial to test ngrok using sinatra I tested the app and showed the correct xml file in the port 4567, the next step was running `./ngrok 4567` but it shows this error `ERROR:  Unrecognized command: 8000`.

Does anyone know what can it be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps you're missing the `http` portion of the ngrok command?

```
./ngrok http 4567
```

Source: https://ngrok.com/docs#expose

Comment: You were right, I finish the tutorial but now Im getting an error in my authentication keys. "SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL"

Comment: Hmmm. I might consider asking a new question and including some of your source code.